# Browser display website in Quirks mode

Tags: php, browser, quirks-mode

I started learn OOP and PHP patterns and I got some troubles using MVC.
I have following files:

**index.php**

```
<?php
    include_once("controller/controller.php");

    $controller = new Controller();

    $controller->view->display();
?>
```

**controller.php**

```
<?php
    class Controller
    {
        public $view;

        public function __construct()
        {
            include_once("view/view.php");
            $this->view = new View();
        }
    }
?>
```

**view.php**

```
<?php
    class View 
    {
        public $layout = "layout/layout.html";

        public function display()
        {
            include $this->layout;
        }
    }
?>
```

**layout.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Dokument bez tytułu</title>
    <style>
      body {
        background-color:#0066CC;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
      }
      #page {
        background-color:#000;
        width:960px;
        height:650px;
        margin:0 auto;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="page"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Anyone could explain me why browser display this website in Quirks mode? The worst thing in this is margin at the top of screen, which is really annoying.
I would be glad for any information about this problem and solution.

Comment: What is the raw HTML and HTTP headers received by the browser?

Comment: insert `&nbsp` inside the div and use border in css to see how they are displaying. what are the errors when you say Quirks mode, is the CSS not getting applied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a valid HTML5 DOCTYPE.

Make sure your PHP files don't have any extraneous spaces or newlines before the opening `<?php` . In your text editor, make sure you are saving them as UTF-8 *without* BOM . On windows, by default, many text editors will insert a BOM (byte order marker), which could be causing garbage to be sent to the screen as the first line of the file. Any content before the DOCTYPE will trigger quirks mode.

Also, I think the `style` tag should be `<style type="text/css">`

Comment: Well, seems like you are right about BOM. **deceze** asked for raw HTML and HTTP headers, here it is: [link](http://i.imgur.com/7BFT0.jpg) Any idea how to fix it? I deleted all spaces

Comment: Yes, open it in a decent text editor (Assuming this is Windows, try Notepad++), and set the encoding to "UTF-8 without BOM". Then re-save the file. If this is the correct answer, please mark it as accepted. Thanks :-)

Comment: Wow, it looks great now! Thanks **Jhong** and **deceze** for help.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Quirks mode is the default if you don't include the exact right DOCTYPE information.  `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` isn't going to cut it.</strike>

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html

Apparently everything I knew was wrong, because after reading this link, apparently *any* doctype at all is supposed to trigger strict mode.

[This link](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/) is pretty awesome, especially the appendix, to try and understand if cross-browser is at work here.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE HTML> is a perfectly valid doctype, it indicates HTML5. (Just saw your edit, so I'm rescinding my downvote)

Answer (score 0):

Put the  above your php tag.  The doctype needs to be on top of the file in order for IE to not go into quirks mode.